# bless something by saying prayers

Tags: vocabulary

In many cultures, a practice is found. The pious people of the community say a prayer over some edible or a drink, blow on it, and then it is believed that this thing is now holy. This is used as a spiritual remedy. Can we say 'bless' here? As in:

> The pious man blessed the water and gave it to the sick man to drink.

Comment: Yes, 'bless' would be the appropriate term.

Comment: Catholic (and Anglo-Catholic) priests "consecrate" wafers of bread and a vessel of wine by saying "words of consecration" over them.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, but that's something more than merely blessing them.

Comment: @Mary - from the OP: "it is believed that this thing is now holy." That's one meaning of   "consecrate": "make or declare something sacred". Or holy. Also Catholic consecration is often called "blessing the host", which makes my point really.

Comment: Often?  I've never heard it.

Comment: Maybe it's an Anglican thing "Last month the majority of lay delegates at the Anglican Sydney Synod voted for lay people to preside at Holy Communion abolishing the centuries old practice of forbidding everyone but ordained clergy from blessing the Host.", but wait... there's a picture called [Christ Blessing the Host](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Christ_Blessing_the_Host_by_Alonso_Cano,_San_Diego_Museum_of_Art.JPG) by Alonzo Claro c.1535.

Answer (score 2):

Bless is entirely appropriate in this context.

You might ask if is better to say "the pious man asked God to bless.."  depending on the belief that people have about effect of prayer.